# connect two server via tor

Tags: configuration, relays, torsocks, iptables

if we have two server let's say server1(92.92.92.92) server2(76.76.76.76).

I'm working on redirect incoming traffic on server1 port 4444 to server2 port 12345,this is easy with iptables rule on server1 like the following:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 76.76.76.76:12345
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

this working well

request --> 4444:server1 <===> 12345:server2

what I need to do is using tor netwok between the two server:

request --> 4444:server1 <===> |tor network| <===> 12345:server2

how I can do what?

I tried to use HiddenServicePort on server2 but I can't forward traffic from HiddenServicePort to another tor hostname ( in server1)

also how i can redirect traffic from iptables to tor specific hostname (server2 hostname)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something to use `socat`, not `iptables`.

You need to employ `socat` on server1 to listen on specific port and forward traffic to server2 through tor. Something along the lines:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:4444 SOCKS4A:localhost:server2:12345,socksport=9050
```

The above command assumes tor running on server1 on the usual port 9050.

You may want to have a look at `socat` man page for additional options, especially for TCP-LISTEN.

Comment: socat work but for one request only, I tested it on apache2(server2) and when the page open socat close and I need to run it again.
how I can apply socat to forward traffic permanently ?

Comment: As I mentioned - have a look at `socat` man page. I think you are looking for `fork` option from `CHILD option group` but you'll have to doublecheck on this.

Answer (score 0):

No `socat` is needed - Tor is like STunnel, so you create a hidden service on server2 *and* rise an OpenVPN server on it - the rest is as simple as it sounds: you will have an internal network like 10.0.0.0/24 for the tunnel and using a static client addresses you will just replace the IP in your iptables rules: **all** the rest of the stuff will be handled by OpenVPN - channel reconnection, interfaces, routing tables e.t.c....